# Is it possible to write large numbers with spaces in the code

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Monte-Carlo control algorithm, and keep getting frustrated when setting the number of steps in the code. It needs to be a large number (thousands, millions...) and it is hard to read it at a glance so I need to count zeros whenever I change it. I tried entering it as

`N_EPISODES = 1 000 000`

or

`N_EPISODES = int('1 000 000')`

or with commas instead of spaces, but none of these work. Is there a way to set large numbers in the code in a human-readable way?

Comment: `1_000_000`, in Python 3.6 and up: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

Comment: Before Python 3.6: `N_EPISODES = int('1 000 000'.replace(' ','') )` or `N_EPISODES = int_with_commas('1,000,000')` using a function you defined earlier.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for, sorry for the dupe.

Answer (score -1):

You can try writing your number in a scientific-style way?
Like 1e6 instead of 1000000 or 1,000,000...